# How to import data from arduino uno

Tags: arduino

I deployed infrared sensors using the Arduino Uno. It print 0 if an object was detected, and 1 if it was not detected. I checked the serial monitor has verified that the data is printed well. My question is, how to import this output value into the external, not in serial monitor. I want to use these date in Android App. Here is my Arduino code.

```
// set parameter 
int sensorPin = A0;     //IR sensor pin num
int sensorValue = 0;    //sensor value parameter
int LED_H = 5;          //pin 5 > LED ON


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);   
  pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(LED_H, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin); //The sensor constantly detects objects

  //Serial.print(sensorValue);     
  //Serial.print("\n");

  if(sensorValue <= 1000 ){    

    digitalWrite(LED_H, LOW); //LED on 
    Serial.print("0");

  }else{

    digitalWrite(LED_H, HIGH);  //LED off
    Serial.print("1"); 

  }
  delay(100);  // System delay 0.1 sec (1=1/1000sec)

}
```

Comment: There are numerous tutorials on how to read from serial on a PC.

Comment: @EKJUN, you'd better specify the communication way between Uno and Android. Are you going to use Bluetooth or WiFi for that matter?

Comment: @Kay, yes, if I need to use Bluetooth or WiFi, I will. But isn't there the way that import data using no Bluetooth or WiFi?

Comment: Please specify what do you mean by "import this value into the external monitor"? Do you mean you want to add a display and show data on it?

Comment: @YakovL What I mean is I want to use the value that the outputs from Arduino in Android App. But I don't know how to use the value from Arduino.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read carefully enough. So what's wrong about serial port? You can transfer data through Bluetooth using serial port and interpret them on the Android side. If the question is regarding the Arduino side, your code is totally ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect hardware WIFI or Bluetooth to send data from your arduino UNO.
This this very simple example to send data across WIFI (ESP8266 Wi-Fi module):
https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/sending-arduino-data-to-webpage